# Using sorting predicates in C++

Tags: c++, comparison, predicate

I have implemented a comparison for struct Track in the function:

```
bool sortingPredicate(const Track& l, const Track& r)
```

then I have a function:

```
void sortPlaylist(std::list<Track>& playlist, bool (*predicate)(const Track& l, const Track& r)) {
    playlist.sort(predicate);
}
```

And I have tried:

```
std::list<Track> mergeWithoutDuplicates(const std::list<Track>& l, const std::list<Track>& r) {
    sortPlaylist(l, sortingPredicate<Track>());
    ...
}
```

And I get for the sortPlaylist-call:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token"
```

What am I missing in the function call / doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Try removing the open and close parentheses at the end of sortingPredicate<Track>

Comment: I get exactly the same error having removed those parentheses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sortingPredicate<Track>()
```

is a function call, you're not passing it as a callback. It should be:

```
sortPlaylist(l, sortingPredicate);
```

also, note that `l` is `const` inside `mergeWithoutDuplicates`, but you're passing it to `sortPlaylist` which expects a non-`const` reference. That's also wrong.

Comment: I get exactly the same error having removed those parentheses... Thanks for the tip on const, though, I have to fix that first.

Comment: @rize my bad, sortingPredicate is not a template function, so the <Track> is illegal there. See edit.

Comment: Thank you! And is it fine to set: "std::list<Track> new_l = l;
 std::list<Track> new_r = r;" and then sort new_l and new_r? Or would you go another way, casting the const away?

Comment: @rize if I intend to return a new list, I'd make the copy. If I intend to sort the existing list, I'd remove the const. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm creating a new list with the the two l and r merged in the new one, without duplicates, so I guess it's best to use the sorted versions of the existing ones in a mergesort way to create the new one, and finally return the new one.